# How to query entity if entity marked with "TableName" attribute in code first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a entity called "Employee"

```
[Table("tbl_Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    //properties
}
```

If I want to fetch all records from employee entity like below

```
var dbContext =new dbContext();
var employeesList=dbContext.Employees.Where(d=>d.Name!=null).ToList();
```

The above line throws exception:

> Such entity does not exists

Please provide the source for Entity framework APIs.

How to filter rows for Employee Entity?

Please suggest

Comment: Provide the code for your dbContext class and the full exception message.